# The green paint on the wall provides a suitable contrast [with/to] the yellow doors

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, sentence-meaning

> The green paint on the wall provides a suitable contrast **with or to** the yellow doors.

If I use **with** will that make this sentence wrong?

Comment: *contrast to* is preferred to *in contrast with*, although the latter is not strictly wrong.

Comment: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contrast+to%2C+contrast+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontrast%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontrast%20with%3B%2Cc0) shows that "contrast to" is much more commonly used. "With" is far less used, though not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention/goal of the sentence is to emphasize the contrast between the **green paint on the wall** and the **yellow doors**. The correct idioms for such a goal may be *in contrast with* or *in contrast to*. Neither is incorrect.

However, your sentence will have to be rewritten thus to make it grammatically correct:

> The green paint on the wall provides a **suitable contrast to** the
>   yellow doors.
>
> The green paint on the wall is **suitably contrasted with** the yellow
>   doors.